# How is the right hand side of an <expr> binding evaluated?

Tags: vimscript, key-bindings

I like using `<cr>` to save a file, except in a `quickfix` window where I want `<cr>` to enter the directory or file shown.

Here's one way to achieve this (works as a `.vimrc` by itself). I'm using the [test described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53491991/) to check for `quickfix` windows.

```
" takes: nothing
" returns: nothing                               
function! RunEnter()                                                                          
        let l:isqf = getwininfo(win_getid())[0]['quickfix']                                   
        if l:isqf                                                                             
                execute '<cr>'                                                                
        else                                                                                  
                execute ':w!'                                                                 
        endif                                                                                 
endfunction 

noremap <cr> :call RunEnter()<cr>
```

This kind of command is easier to test, though, if it returns a string with the command to be executed rather than calling into `execute`.

```
" This vimrc does NOT work.

" takes: nothing
" returns: command to be executed
function! RunEnter()
        let l:isqf = getwininfo(win_getid())[0]['quickfix'] 
        if l:isqf                                                                             
                return '<cr>'                                                               
        else                                                                                  
                return ':w!<cr>'                                                                 
        endif    
endfunction

nnoremap <expr> <cr> RunEnter()
```

This `.vimrc`, however, doesn't have the expected behavior when you press `<cr>`.

For example, if you visit the `.vimrc` itself and then press `<cr>`, you get `:w!<cr>` verbatim as the command line. The `<cr>` is being treated as `"<cr>"` rather than as a literal naming a key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<expr>` merely interprets the string as a command, it does not perform conversion of "escape codes" like `<cr>`.  This is a feature only of whatever is written in the map line.

Instead you need to create escape codes like this: `"\<cr>"` e.g.,

```
return ":w!\<cr>"
```

You must use `"` in this context for vim to interpret it specially, which won't happen with `'`.